# How to submit updated photo only after change was submitted not during on change?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to have functionality to where a user has a default profile picture upon logging in. He then has the option to update his profile picture.

I got 95% of it working I'm just stuck on the last step.

the process works like this:

1) Upon logging in, profile picture is set to a default picture. In the MYSQL database I have a profilePic field set to a default profilePic

2) when the user changes his/her picture, it changes the state of profilePic

3) when they submit the request to change the picture my (onSubmit function), it uploads the updated picture to AWS S3 and updates the DB field to whatever the updated file name he/she chose.

However, this presents a problem because when the picture gets changed, it breaks the default picture I have on there (because I changed the state) and no picture is available in S3 on change, it only changes on submit. And the thing is, I need the filename change on state to send to the server.

so my question is how can I have it to where after they submit and the picture is available in my S3 directory and db changes get made, that state doesn't get affected until submit happens?

I think I perhaps need to use a life cycle method but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is my code:

If needed, I'll upload my db query and server code as well.

**View:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../common/Header';
import Base64 from 'base-64';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import profileService from '../../services/Profilepage';

class Profilepage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            userName: '',
            profilePic: '',
            fileObject: '',
            fileType: '',
            fileSize: '',
            filePayload: '',
            errorMsg: false,
            errorMsg2: false,
        }
    }

    async userStatus(){
        // Check if the user is logged in
        if(localStorage.getItem('userData') === null) {
            this.setState({redirect: true})
        } else {
            // Parse the data
            const userObject = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

            this.setState({
                firstName: userObject.firstName,
                lastName: userObject.lastName,
                email: userObject.email,
                userName: userObject.userName
            })
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({
            show:false,
            // clear file state when modal closes
            fileType: '',
            fileSize: '',
            fileObject: '',
            filePayload: ''
        });
    }

    handleShow(){
        this.setState({
            show:true
        });
    }

    onChange(e){
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        this.setState({
            profilePic: file.name,
            fileObject: e.target.files[0],
            fileType: file.type,
            fileSize: file.size,
        });

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                filePayload: e.target.result
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state);

        //Check if a uploaded photo was taken.
        if(this.state.fileObject === ''){
            this.setState({
                errorMsg: true
            })
        }
        else {

            const updateData = {
                userName: this.state.userName,
                profilePic: this.state.profilePic,
                fileType: this.state.fileType,
                fileSize: this.state.fileSize,
                filePayload: this.state.filePayload,
            }

            const updateprofileData = await profileService.updatePhoto(updateData)

            //console.log(updateprofileData);

            // Reload the page with users updated photo.
            location.href='/Profilepage';

        }
    }
    // Select users profilepic in database. Set it to state. However, this is what I'm stuck on cause if I change a picture with the onchange method, the picture will break because in S3, the picture isn't available until after the user has submitted the change.
    async selectData(){
        const selectData = {
            profilePic: this.state.profilePic,
            userName: this.state.userName
        }
        const selectprofileData = await profileService.selectPhoto(selectData)

        this.setState({
            profilePic: 'mys3linkishere' + this.state.profilePic
        })
    }

    async componentDidMount(){

        await this.userStatus();

        await this.selectData();

    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.redirect){
            return(<Redirect to={'/'}/>)
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Header />
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-5" id="profile-left">
                        <h1>Welcome, {this.state.userName}</h1>

                        <div className="img-rounded">

                            <img src={this.state.profilePic} alt="profile picture" />

                        </div>

                        <Button onClick={this.handleShow}>Upload New Photo</Button>

                        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                            <form
                                method="POST"
                                onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                            >
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Upload New Photo</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                {/* Please upload a photo. */}
                                {this.state.errorMsg === true ? <span style={{color: 'red'}}>Please upload a photo</span> : null}
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    className="form-control-file"
                                    name="profilePic"
                                    onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                                />
                            </Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button type="submit" onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)} bsStyle="primary">Upload Photo</Button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                            </form>
                        </Modal>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profilepage;
```

**Model:**

```js
var db = require('../dbconnection');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// AWS configuration
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '....',
    secretAccessKey: '....'
})

var profilePage = {
    // Update users profilepic in database and insert photo in s3 bucket
    updatePhoto: function(data, callback){

        let uniqueprofilePic = data.userName + '-' + data.profilePic;

        db.query('UPDATE users SET profilePic="'+uniqueprofilePic+'" WHERE userName="'+data.userName+'"')
        //console.log(data);

        var buf = new Buffer(data.filePayload.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'mysimplebucket',
            Key: uniqueprofilePic,
            Body: buf,
            ContentType: data.fileType,
            ACL: 'public-read',
        };
        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
                return data
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
        callback(true);
    },
    selectPhoto: function(data, callback){
        db.query('SELECT * from users WHERE userName="'+data.userName+'"', callback)
    }
}

module.exports = profilePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the way I understand the situation is that when onChange is called, you're setting `this.state.profilePic` state as just the name of the file. As a consequence, when render method is called again, the `img` attribute is looking for the address of the file. Instead its just getting the file name.

If you want to keep the way things are, then I'd suggest you update onChange method to include method call to upload the File to S3 (before you `setState` in Onchange) and also make sure the network round trip completes before the `seState`. You can then update your DB during onSubmit. I personally find the solution a bit nasty, but it'll get stuff done.

OR

<s>You can set the complete local file path as a value to `this.state.profilePic` during your onChange.</s>
I realized Chrome doesn't let you set local file path.

Editing onChange function like this should solve it-

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            filePayload: e.target.result,
            profilePic: reader.result
        });
    };
```

And remove the setState from a few lines before.
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm heading home now. Let me see if this will work and I'll get back to you tomorrow if it works or any concerns I have.

Comment: I have a question, when I chose the second option and I set the state of my change to local file path, it still broke so is that not an option as well? it changed my src to `C:/thefilepath.png`

Comment: Try the edit I mentioned in my answer. I tried it on my local machine and it works! The concept is that reader.result gives you the uploaded file's URL. Refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your help! I learned a bit more about how files work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming after this line of code, you will know whether your data is submitted correctly to the server or not:

```
const updateprofileData = await profileService.updatePhoto(updateData)
```

Then you can set `fileUpload` to true at this point, since it's certain that the URL of the image is ready.

```
async onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Check if a uploaded photo was taken.
    if(this.state.profilePic === ''){
        this.setState({
            errorMsg: true
        })
    } else {
        const updateData = {
            userName: this.state.userName,
            profilePic: this.state.profilePic,
            fileType: this.state.fileType,
            fileSize: this.state.fileSize,
            filePayload: this.state.filePayload,
        }

        const updateprofileData = await profileService.updatePhoto(updateData)

        // an equivalent condition here to check if your data is submitted
        if (!!updateprofileData) {
            this.setState({ fileUpload: true })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While this does work and it changes the image on submit, when I refresh the page, the profile image goes back to the default profile image and doesn't get updated.

Comment: @Curious13 That's another problem already. Because (1) when you refresh `fileUpload` is init as `false` again and (2) at `componentDidMount` you does not check if same profile was submitted to server or not; so your component is unaware of last submission to the server.

Comment: I suggest that instead of taking data from `localStorage` at `componentDidMount`, check for data in server instead. If it's existed, update your state and set `fileUpload` to true. Your code relating to `localStorage` seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I can't figure out how to only change the picture when the user hits submit on the updated photo not during on change?